# OpenCV Program cant start because MSVCP110D.dll is missing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, windows-7-x64

I installed OpenCV 2.4.9 on windows 7 , 64 bit,  with Visual studio 2010.

Simple "hello world" in debug and release mode works perfectly fine, but my opencv programs give this MSVCP110D.dll is missing  error in debug mode.  release mode works perfectly fine.

I understand that MSVCP110D.dll is a debug dll from Visual Studio 2012, so what it is doing here with my Visual studio 2010?

I installed redistributable 2012, but still same error is coming?

What is the work around then ?

Comment: Are you linking with correct opencv lib files? You have to link with the ones which are present in the **vc10** folder, not in the **vc11** folder.

Comment: @sgar91 you mean in properties->linker-> general ? yes , I have added vc10/lib in both release and debug.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem through replacing the OPENCV .lib and .dll with the proper version regarding my VS. I used VS2013 but tried to used OPENCV compiled in VS2012. So I guess that is the reason for this error message.